# How can I store data for compiling leaderboards?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cassandra-2.1

Firslty I'd like to note that I currently only using 1 node because it handles my current needs just fine. And also, I'm using nodejs for all of this.

Now, here's my issue. There's a cassandra table "playerdata" which is storing millions of player's data in a video game.

I want to compile leaderboards, and it's clear to me I won't be able to do so via this table.

I need to retrieve everybody's data, then loop through in varying ways and compile various leaderboards.

However, is there another method which is good on performance?

My first thought was maps, but then I realized there is a limit to these.
Would the best option be to switch to a SQL database for leaderboards?

Comment: My understanding of a leaderboard is the following: display players ranking based on some criteria. If is like this, I would create a table for each leadeboard. Of course you will duplicate some data, but this is how Cassandra works. Each query for a leaderboard will have its own table. In order to obtain more advice you should share more on your model, restrictions and what kind of search criteria your leaderboards should satisfy...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cassandra support of order by clause. but order by is supported only for cluster key. so if you want to create leader board for example base on game points, you can create schema like - ((gameId), userId, Points).

Comment: Could you provide an example of how I'd then fetch them with this schema? Edit: I'm assuming it's just SELECT userid, points FROM example WHERE gameid='1' ORDER BY points DESC for example?

Comment: Yes thats correct, and you can limit the results as per your needs,

Comment: Would it be possible to have multiple options to order by? - let's say you want one leaderboard for cash, and another for level

Comment: In that case you should consider creating different tables for each case.  Cassandra doesn't facilitate order by while retrieving of data, instead user should create table in a way so that data is already ordered as per need while insertion itself.   As 1 table can't have 2 type of ordering sequences, so for each type of desired ordering sequence you should consider separate table. To keep data consistent across all tables you might consider logged batch statement while insertion.